# Issue passing mutable Arc reference to hyper service_fn handler

Tags: rust, future, smart-pointers, rust-tokio, hyper

I've been trying the following

Relevant imports and code shown

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread;
use hyper::rt::{self, Future, Stream};
use hyper::service::service_fn;
use hyper::{Body, Request, Response, Server, StatusCode};

pub struct ChallengeState;
pub struct ChallengeResponse;

type BoxFut<'a> = Box<Future<Item = Response<Body>, Error = hyper::Error> + Send + 'a>;

fn handle_challengeproof<'a>(
    req: Request<Body>,
    challenge: &Arc<Mutex<ChallengeState>>,
) -> BoxFut<'a> {
    let resp = req.into_body().concat2().map(move |body| {
        let challenge_lock = challenge.lock().unwrap();
        Response::builder()
        .status(StatusCode::OK)
        .body(Body::from("test"))
        .unwrap()
    });
    Box::new(resp)
}

fn handle<'a>(
    req: Request<Body>,
    challenge: &Arc<Mutex<ChallengeState>>,
) -> BoxFut<'a> {
    handle_challengeproof(req, challenge)
}

pub fn run_listener(
    challenge: Arc<Mutex<ChallengeState>>,
) -> thread::JoinHandle<()> {
    let addr = ([127, 0, 0, 1], 9999).into();

    let listener_service = move || {
        let challenge = Arc::clone(&challenge);
        service_fn(move |req: Request<Body>| {
            handle(req, &challenge)
        })
    };

    let server = Server::bind(&addr)
        .serve(listener_service)
        .map_err(|_| () );

    thread::spawn(move || {
        rt::run(server);
    })
}
```

I've been trying to avoid an extra clone of Arc by passing a reference to the handle method but can't seem to get around this. Avoiding the lifetime on handle() got a different error regarding futures asking for static lifetime.

Code updated with only relevant stuff @ https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=10ea31450e88a122455006760d7fcdd1

Comment: A reference to an `Arc` doesn't make much sense IMHO. You either pass `&ChallengeState` if you want to do something with it or `Arc` when you need to store it.

Comment: This Arc is shared with other threads. I'm thinking of a reference to avoid having to clone on each service_fn call.

Comment: I've updated the code with the relevant problem only.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of an `Arc` is that it counts how many references there are, which happens when it is cloned. Passing around references to an `Arc` defeats the point.

Instead of passing references, pass the `Arc` itself. So `handle`'s signature becomes:

```
fn handle<'a>(
    req: Request<Body>,
    challenge: Arc<Mutex<ChallengeState>>,
) -> BoxFut<'a>
```

Passing the `Arc` by references from the closure isn't possible because you would be referencing something that immediately goes out of scope. Instead, *move* the `Arc` into `handle`:

```
let listener_service = move || {
    service_fn(move |req: Request<Body>| handle(req, challenge))
};
```

Comment: This gives a different problem: "this closure implements `FnOnce`, not `Fn`". Challenge needs to be moved every time not once.

Comment: @hellow sorry it's mostly unit-tests. Anyway the problem seems quite straightforward. I'm passing a reference to an Arc and the compiler can't make out the lifetime of the original Arc to check if it's lifetime will match from what I understand.

Comment: @NikosKostoulas Would you say that [this is a minimal reproduction](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3899d8aeef32153ee6048eb74a7ab884) or your problem?

Comment: yep with `&'a Arc<Mutex<ChallengeState>>,`

Comment: @NikosKostoulas So is this the fix you are looking for? https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8132244742bbd18a528a85a191dfea8a

Comment: Yes but I get an additional problem when I use another method where I unlock the Arc Mutex! https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=10ea31450e88a122455006760d7fcdd1

Comment: Weird issue right? And when I try to apply `'a` lifetime to challenge in all methods I get an error in run_listener.